# Speeding up this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

This is my query which takes about 1.5 seconds. Can I lower this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NAME asc) peta_rn, 
        peta_query.* 
     FROM 
         (SELECT 
              BOOK, PAGETRIMMED, NAME, TYPE, PDF 
         FROM 
              CCWiseDocumentNames2 cdn
         INNER JOIN 
              CCWiseInstr2 cwi ON cwi.ID = cdn.ID) as peta_query) peta_paged 
WHERE 
    peta_rn > 1331900 AND peta_rn <= 1331950
```

These are my table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CCWiseDocumentNames2](
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [BK_PG] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [NAME] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [OTHERNAM] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [TYPE] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [INDEXNAME] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CCWiseInstr2](
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [BK_PG] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [ITYPE] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [BOOK] [int] NULL,
    [PAGE] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [NOBP] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DESC] [varchar](240) NULL,
    [TIF] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [INDEXNAME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CONFIRM] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [PDF] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [PAGETRIMMED] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [PageINT] [int] NULL,
    [PageCHAR] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [IdAuto] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This is my execution plan:

[image]

As you can see it is 97% clustered index seek and 3% index scan. Any way to improve this query further?

Comment: Index seek in good right? Its the scan you want to avoid.

Comment: But the scan is just 3%. Do you mean there is no way to further improve this query?

Comment: it seems you have index, what are the columns you have index on ?

Comment: peta_rn is a row number. Doesnt seems like you have a proper primary key setup or at least a unique index field on the ID.

Comment: Do you ever actually get users visit pages that far on?

Comment: Can you run [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650699.aspx)?

Comment: @Martin: Actually I have a grid and it has a last button. If the user presses it, then yes it would fire up this query.

Comment: The key to speeding this up is to add a where clause to your peta_query derived table.  That way the rest of the query is processing fewer records.  The exact where clause depends on your requirements, but the date field in CCWiseInstr2 has the potential to restrict you to recent records only.

Comment: @DanBracuk: But on what basis, He is filtering records on row
_number later ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I speed up this Row\_Number query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18843146/how-do-i-speed-up-this-row-number-query)

Comment: @AshutoshArya, he is looking for row numbers on all the records in that derived table.  The fewer records he has to find row numbers for, the less time it will take.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add rownumber on the fly to more than a million rows and expect a where clause will instantly recognize those rows with the newly generated rownumbers.

Answer (score 0):

Because I don't have that volume of data, can only provide some options for your consideration:

Dedicate the clustered index for Name column (other than ID)
Make the join after you get row_number over name. 
Include the three columns from CCWiseInstr2 into a non-clustered index on ID column. This could save some hard disk spindle's movement. Perfomance gain could only be observed with large volume of data.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX  [idx2_ID_include] ON [dbo].[CCWiseInstr2] ([ID] ASC) INCLUDE ( [BOOK], [PDF], [PAGETRIMMED]) 
GO

With a as (
    Select * 
    from (  SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NAME asc) as  peta_rn, ID, 
                    type 
            from    CCWiseDocumentNames2) as Temp 
            where   peta_rn > 1331900 AND peta_rn <= 1331950
) 
select  a.peta_rn, 
        a.type, 
        b.book, 
        b.PAGETRIMMED, 
        b.PDF
from    a 
join    CCWiseInstr2 as b on a.id = b.id
```